# How we can use bottom sheet in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am start to migrate my project to jetpack compose, and I am learning jetpack compose now, I want to use bottom sheet in my project, I search on internet to use bottom sheet, I find some codes, I use it in my app,  every things looks good, but when I run the my app, it  crashed, I am not sure where I mistake? Is there any other  solution?

```
    class MyActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            ModalBottomSheetLayoutScreen()
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ModalBottomSheetLayoutScreen() {
    val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = 
  ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetContent = {

        },
        sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
        sheetBackgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
        // scrimColor = Color.Red,  // Color for the fade background when you open/close the drawer
    ) {
        Scaffold(

            backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white)
        ) {
            MyScreen(scope = scope, state = modalBottomSheetState)
        }
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    scope: CoroutineScope, state: ModalBottomSheetState
) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
           

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(170.dp),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally

                    ) {
                  
                        Text(
                            text = "click",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .clickable {
                                    scope.launch {
                                        state.show()
                                    }
                              }  
                        )}} }

   
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ModalBottomSheetLayoutScreenPreview() {
    ModalBottomSheetLayoutScreen()
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: You should share your crash log to be sure what's the cause. But if i'm to guess i would say `sheetBackgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.white)` this might be the reason if there is white color in your color file.

Comment: @Thracian, no error in logcat, it is not about color, I miss some point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It crashes because your `sheetContent` is empty. I've [reported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216693030) this bug. In a real app you should have some content, otherwise you don't need `ModalBottomSheetLayout` at all.

Specifying any view inside `sheetContent` solves the problem.